# Need the "top five "id's" from this query

Tags: java, mysql

I had someone helping me earlier and have gotten close, What I need to to get the top five "id's" from this query. What is happening is am am getting on one id and not the top five. Anyone know how to correct this? Here is the query:

```
(
SELECT id,
     firstName,
     lastName,
     SUM(fileSize) AS TotalBytes,
     SUM(fileSize)/COUNT(*) AS Average
FROM   roster_cs368 AS a
JOIN htmp_cs368  AS b USING (id)
) UNION (
SELECT id,
     firstName,
     lastName,
     SUM(fileSize) AS TotalBytes,
     SUM(fileSize)/COUNT(*) AS Average
FROM   roster_cs368 AS a
JOIN atmp_cs368  AS b USING (id)
)
ORDER BY TotalBytes DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Thank You! This is also part of a larger program, hence the java tag.

Here is the schema:

```
mysql> select * from roster_cs368
-> ;
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id     | firstName | lastName  |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| apn7cf | Allen     | Newton    |
| atggg3 | andrew    | goebel    |
```

Where is is the primary key,

```
mysql> select * from htmp_cs368;
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+----------------------+
| filePerms  | numLinks | id         | idGroup  | fileSize | month | day  | time  | fileName             |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+----------------------+
| drwx------ |        2 | schulte    | faculty  |      289 | Nov   |    7 | 2011  | Java                 |
| -rw-r--r-- |        1 | schulte    | faculty  |      136 | Apr   |   29 | 2012  | LD                   |
| drwxr-xr-x |        3 | schulte    | faculty  |      177 | Mar   |   20 | 2012  | Upgrade              |
```

No primary key here,

```
mysql> select * from atmp_cs368;
+------------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| filePerms  | numLinks | id           | idGroup  | fileSize | month | day  | time  | fileName                    |
+------------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| drwxr-xr-x |        2 | remierm      | 203      |      245 | Sep   |   17 | 14:40 | 148360_sun_studio_12        |
| drwx---rwx |       31 | antognolij   | sasl     |     2315 | Oct   |   24 | 12:28 | 275                         |
| -rwx------ |        1 | kyzvdb       | student  |       36 | Sep   |   19 | 13:05 | 275hh                       |
```

and no primary key here.

What my query is:

```
produce a list of the five members of roster_cs368,
    and their ids who use the most space (number of bytes)
    in htmp_cs368 and atmp_cs368 in descending order--
    greediest first.  display total number of bytes and
    average size of file
```

Comment: Define top 5... And maybe share the schema with us, give us an example of the expected output, what is the actual output and so on

Comment: @Tim schema and query added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
(
SELECT id,
     firstName,
     lastName,
     SUM(fileSize) AS TotalBytes,
     SUM(fileSize)/COUNT(*) AS Average
FROM   roster_cs368 AS a
JOIN htmp_cs368  AS b USING (id)
) UNION (
SELECT id,
     firstName,
     lastName,
     SUM(fileSize) AS TotalBytes,
     SUM(fileSize)/COUNT(*) AS Average
FROM   roster_cs368 AS a
JOIN atmp_cs368  AS b USING (id)
)
) as somealias ORDER BY TotalBytes DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but it give me an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM(
(
SELECT id,
     firstName,
     lastName,
     SUM(fileSize) AS TotalByt' at line 1`

Comment: Yes it had an error, I've updated my answer with a fixed version, please try that.

Comment: still only getting 1 user and then null. I have updated my original post to include the schema.